# Index was outside the bounds of the array error when processing .svd file

Tags: powershell

```
clear

# Powershell scripts used to mask Private Personal Information on data files.

# path to PERM file
$path = "MYURL\ABS.SVD"

# get file content
$content = Get-Content $path

$content | ForEach-Object {
    $mask50 = 'X' * 50   # variables to makes fields by letter according to length
    $mask30 = 'Y' * 30
    $mask20 = 'A' * 20
    $mask08 = 'Z' * 8
    $mask05 = 'B' * 5
    $mask16 = 'C' * 16

    # if statement, if the string is at position 0-10, and begins with
    # 'STARTDELIV' then run replace statement
    if ($_.Substring(0,10) -eq 'STARTDELIV') {
        $SplitString = $_.Split('|')

        $SplitString[3] = $mask30    # Fields : To Fax Name
        $SplitString[4] = $mask20    # Fields : To fax Number
        $SplitString[9] = $mask50    # Fields : To EMail Address

        $SplitString -join '|'
    } else {
        $_
    }
} | Out-File "MYURL\ABS-Output.svd" -Encoding ASCII
```

I have a script which masked certain fields in a data file (fields seperated by '|'). I have done a lot of these and they work fine. However, when I copy this exact file to another folder to use a different data file (.svd) I get the "Index was outside the bounds of the array", I've seen a few other threads on this but none really answer my query.

Curious as to why it still works in a particular folder location but not the other (I am changing the input and output urls to direct to the new folder).

Error below:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
AtMYURL-Masked-Fields.ps1:28 char:3
+         $SplitString[3] = $mask30                                                    #To Fax Name
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException
```

Comment: Update: The script runs successfully in that the fields are masked, but I still get the error in the console?

Comment: Check the count of the $SplitString array. If it is less than 9, then you are referencing something outside of the array. Perhaps not all records in the file have enough fields.

Comment: Sounds like you have at least one line that has less than 10 parts,

Comment: Sure would help to see the actual error. You should get into the habit of posting that when you ask questions.

Comment: @lit There are 11 records on the file so that should be fine.

Comment: @EBGreen This could be the case about the 10 parts, there are some lines with less than 9 fields. But not a line that begins with STARTDELIV?

Comment: Error:

Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At \\ILIFE035\Appl_Dev\Output_Management\Project Management\2017 Projects\Masking sensitive 
data\TopUps\TopUps-Masked-Fields.ps1:28 char:3
+         $SplitString[3] = $mask30                                                    #To Fax Name
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException


There are several similar errors in the console

Comment: Well I don't have the data so I'm not sure why you ended that with a question mark. Please post the error. Or at least tell us the specific line that throws the error.

Comment: Please edit the question with the error. When you do, please format it so that it can be easily read.

Comment: The error is extremely clear. Regardless of what you ***think*** the situation is, there is at least one line that has less than 4 fields

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking why. As it works without errors before. Why would a line that doesn't start with STARTDELIV be affected by the SplitString

Comment: There is at least one record starting with STARTDELIV that does not have enough fields. `find /I "STARTDELIV" "MYURL\ABS.SVD"`

Comment: `Select-String -Path "MYURL\ABS.SVD" -Pattern "STARTDELIV"`

Comment: Thank you, that was it. It was a large file so I went through each StartDeliv line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @lit

"There is at least one record starting with STARTDELIV that does not have enough fields. find /I "STARTDELIV" "MYURL\ABS.SVD" "